# How to parallelize function calls with MPI or OpenMP

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

**1st question:**

I wonder how I can parallelize function calls to the same function, but with different input parameters in a for loop. For example (C code):

```
//a[i] and b[i] are defined as elements of a list with 2 columns and N rows
//i is the row number

#pragma omp parallel
{
char cmd[1000];
  #pragma omp for nowait
  for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    //call the serial programm
    sprintf(cmd, "./serial_program %f %f", a[i], b[i]);
    system(cmd);
  }
}
```

If I just apply a pragma omp for (+the omp header of course) nothing happens. Maybe this is not possible with OpenMP, but would it be possible with MPI and how would it look like then? I have experience only with OpenMP so far, but not with MPI.
update:  defined cmd within parallel region

**Status: solved**

**2nd question:**

If i have a OpenMP parallelized program and i want to use it among different nodes within a cluster, how can i distribute the calls among the different nodes with MPI and how would i compile it?

```
//a[i] and b[i] are defined as elements of a list with 2 columns and N rows
//i is the row number

  for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    //call the parallelized program
    sprintf(cmd, "./openmp_parallelized_program %f %f", a[i], b[i]);
    system(cmd);
  }
```

**Status: unsolved**

Comment: did you set a number of threads for omp (`omp_set_num_threads()`)?

Comment: I just set export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 before execution

Comment: did you try using `#pragma omp parallel for`? You must have `#pragma omp parallel` somewhere to let omp spawn threads.

Comment: O well I forgot it in the example above, but in my original code i did not forget it. Code updated^

Comment: The problem in question 1 was that i defined cmd outside the parallel region, such that the program was executed with the same input parameters by all threads. I added a second question^^

Comment: `cmd` must be declared `private`, otherwise as different threads try to write to it, you might end up with a garbled command name. Check the return code of `system()` and keep in mind that the OpenMP runtime might not be happy if threads try to `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

MPI is a method to communicate between nodes of a computing cluster. It enables one motherboard to talk to another. MPI is for clusters and large computing tasks, it is not for parallelizing desktop applications.

Communications in MPI are done by explicitly sending and receiving data.

Unlike OpenMP, there is no #pragma that will automatically facilitate parallelization.

Also there is something really messed up about the code that you posted, specifically, it is a C program that acts like a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10
for i in `seq 1 $N`;
do
./program $i &
done
```

On many clusters calls to `system` will execute only on the host node, resulting in no speedup and io problems. The command you showed is wholly unworkable.

Comment: MPI is an abstract paradigm for data exchange via explicit message passing between processes with isolated address spaces. This could map to any kind of hardware, from multicore desktops to multinode clusters and specialised supercomputer architectures.

Comment: @HristoIliev It certainly will run, but its not the most efficient way. Explicitly waiting for A->A memory transfers + mutexes is perhaps worse than using just a mutex. From my understanding some of the fastest codes use pthreads/OpenMP locally and communicate with each other using MPI. Looking at your profile you probably already know this :-)

Comment: It's not always black and white. Speaking from experience, there are surprisingly many cases, where MPI programs execute just as fast (if not even faster) as their threaded counterparts.

Comment: Well if the system command is unworkable on multiple nodes, how can i execute an OpenMP parallelized program with different input parameters on different nodes?

Comment: @user2015521, many clusters run under the supervision of a resource manager of a kind, e.g. LSF, Torque/PBS, SGE/OGE/OGS, SLURM, etc. In this case you can submit an array job. Or you can simply submit one job per program invocation if the particular resource manager does not support array jobs.

Answer (score 0):

With MPI you would do something like:

```
int rank, size;

MPI_Init();
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

int start = (rank*N)/size;
int end = ((rank+1)*N)/size;

for (i = start; i < end; i++)
{
   sprintf(cmd, "./openmp_parallelized_program %f %f", a[i], b[i]);
   system(cmd);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

Then run the MPI job with one process per node. There is a caveat though. Some MPI implementations do not allow processes to call `fork()` under certain conditions (and `system()` calls `fork()`), e.g. if they communicate over RDMA-based networks like InfiniBand. Instead, you could merge both programs in order to create one hybrid MPI/OpenMP program.